# WebGL - What are some performant ways to select 3d objects?

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, webgl, raytracing

I am interested in 'picking' (i.e. selecting) objects in my canvas by clicking on it.

- I am not interested in picking by color (as that doesn't allow me to know which object has been clicked)
- I am not interested in using gl.RenderMode(GL_SELECT). Anyway, my understanding is that this is obsolete and may not even be supported in WebGL.

**Updated**

I have an idea. Please let me know if this idea is flawed.
I have a 3d world and a camera object - meaning i have a camera position, lookat veector, and up vector.

> My idea is this:

"Fire" a vector/ray through the 3d world (this vector is basically the camera's lookat vector).
    Then i just iterate through all of my 3d objects and check if it intersects with this ray/vector and return the object which is the closest distance to the camera.
    My collision detection, for the time being, would be a simple bounding sphere.
    I can get more sophisticated later by using a more complex/accurate collision detection.

> The only **gap** I see is this:

I do not know how to create the ray/vector based off of the mouse coordinate. I can get the (X, Y) of the mouse click on the canvas element. But not sure how to translate this to be the starting point of the ray/vector in world coordinate.

Any thoughts on this approach?
Any ideas regarding the gap concern that i have?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364693/how-to-get-object-in-webgl-3d-space-from-a-mouse-click-coordinate
or perhaps this one: https://www.udacity.com/course/viewer#!/c-cs291/l-124106599/m-175393398

Comment: I would like to NOT use a 3rd party library.

Comment: If you don't know how to get a vector based on the mouse coordinate, then you could look at the library functions and see how they do it. Watch the film in the second link, it explains alot.

Comment: A helpful keyword is "Unproject", using the mouse x/y and 2 different z values (I use -1 and 1)

Comment: Please take a look at my reply on a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23644470/how-to-convert-mouse-coordinate-on-screen-to-3d-coordinate/23645092#23645092

Comment: Ok, but im just basically asking for peoples opinion on my approach to this problem. I gave specific example of how im thinking about doing this. But basically i do not see why unprojecting is necessary. If i have a camera location plus its lookat vector, then i have enough to cast a ray. What is wrong with this simple approach?

Comment: @AlvinfromDiaspar Unprojection is the process of getting the ray. If you already have it, then cool, go cast the ray.